# Actual values of the maximum value in each interval

Tags: r

Lets assume

```
x = c(1, 2, 3.5, 4, 6, 7.5, 8, 9, 10, 11.5, 12) 
y = c(2.5, 6.5) 
I = split(x, findInterval(x, y))
f = function(I$'i', x) {
        d = pmax(outer(x, I$'i', "-"), 0)
        colSums(d - d^2/2)
}
```

I want to calculate the value of f(I$'i', x) in each values of each interval and then find which I$'i' actual value have the maximum value of f(I$'i', x ) in each interval. for example if we have three intervals , my result should be three values of x which f(I$'i', x) is maximum in each interval. how can i find these values?
In addition, it should be mentioned that in each iteration of my code the value of vector y changes.

I wrote this code but i can not find the actual values of the maximum value in each interval:

```
for(i in 0:length(I)-1){
    max.value = I$'i'[which.max(f(I$'i', x))]
}
```

and i got this error:
Error in pmax(outer(x, I, "-"), 0) : 
  cannot mix 0-length vectors with others

Comment: The definition of `f` doesn't work in R for me, are you sure that's what you're entering into R?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `I$'i'` is a syntax error. To convert a number `i` to the string try (e.g.) `i <- 0; I[[i]]`. This is like doing `I$'0'` but a bit less odd-looking and it allows `i` to be a variable.

Comment: On a slightly different note, `0:length(I)-1` doesn't give the output you expect: `0:length(I)-1` = `[1] -1  0  1  2`. You need to put brackets so that R knows the order of operation you intend: `0:(length(I)-1)` = `[1]  0  1  2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is attempting to index the `i`th element of the list. Doing `I$'i'` is trying to get the element of the list corresponding to the string `'i'`, which doesn't exist:

```
> i <- 1
> I$'i'
NULL
```

To fix this, you should index a list using the `[[..]]` notation (which indexes them in order, i.e. `I[[1]]` = `I$'0'`):

```
> i <- 1
> I[[i]]
[1] 1 2
> I$'0' # to illustrate the indexing
[1] 1 2
```

Assuming that `f` is just meant to take a vector (rather than an index into `I`), its definition should be something like:

```
f = function(vec, x) {
        d = pmax(outer(x, vec, "-"), 0)
        colSums(d - d^2/2)
}
```

And the loop like:

```
for (i in 1:length(i)) {
     max.value = I[[i]][which.max(f(I[[i]], x))]
}
```

Note that you can iterate directly over the elements of a list, you don't need to index each one individually, so we could also do:

```
for (vec in I) {
     max.value = vec[which.max(f(vec, x))]
}
```

(Also, you might want something slightly different to what you have, since in each loop `max.value` is overwritten.)

Comment: @BensorBeny, if this answer solves your question you should click the outline of a checkmark next to it to indicate it as "accepted". (You should do it for your other questions too.)